# Unable to display codepen icon

Tags: html, css, icons, instagram, font-awesome

I'm trying to use font-awesome icons but I'm not able to see codepen icon. All other icons works fine. Is there any way where I can get the new Instagram icon color merged with this color? I tried using other icons provided by font awesome and it seemed to work. I also tried changing the positions of codepen icon with other icon but it didn't seemed to work. Another thing, the animation seems to be working on the place where the icon is but it doesn't show anthing.

```css
html {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

body {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Wrapper */

.icon-button {
  background-color: white;
  /* border-radius: 2.6rem;*/
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  height: 2.6rem;
  line-height: 2.6rem;
  margin: 0 5px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  width: 2.6rem;
}


/* Circle */

.icon-button span {
  /* border-radius: 0;*/
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  width: 0;
}

.icon-button:hover span {
  border-radius: 25px;
  width: 2.6rem;
  height: 2.6rem;
  /*border-radius: 2.6rem;*/
  margin: -1.3rem;
  /*transform: rotate(20deg);*/
}


/* Icons */

.icon-button i {
  background: none;
  color: white;
  height: 2.6rem;
  left: 0;
  line-height: 2.6rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  width: 2.6rem;
  z-index: 10;
}

.facebook span {
  background-color: #3B5998;
}

.instagram span {
  background-color: #c32aa3;
  /*background-color: linear-gradient(#c32aa3, #c4302b);*/
}

.codepen span {
  background-color: #cb2027;
}

.icon-button .icon-facebook {
  color: #3B5998;
}

.icon-button .fa-instagram {
  color: #c32aa3;
}

.icon-button .fa-codepen {
  color: #cb2027;
}

.icon-button:hover .icon-facebook,
.icon-button:hover .fa-instagram,
.icon-button:hover .fa-codepen {
  color: white;
}

@media all and (max-width: 680px) {
  .icon-button {
    border-radius: 1.6rem;
    font-size: 0.8rem;
    height: 1.6rem;
    line-height: 1.6rem;
    width: 1.6rem;
  }
  .icon-button:hover span {
    width: 1.6rem;
    height: 1.6rem;
    border-radius: 1.6rem;
    margin: -0.8rem;
  }
  /* Icons */
  .icon-button i {
    height: 1.6rem;
    line-height: 1.6rem;
    width: 1.6rem;
  }
  body {
    padding: 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<a href="#" class="icon-button facebook"><i class="icon-facebook"></i><span></span></a>
<a href="#" class="icon-button instagram"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i><span></span></a>
<a href="#" class="icon-button codepen"><i class="fa fa-codepen"></i><span></span></a>
```

Comment: This is not a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Okay. I edited the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to import the Font Awesome `CSS` into your example.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

I was having issues getting the Facebook icon to show, due to an error in the `<i>` `class`:

```html
<a href="#" class="icon-button facebook">
  <i class="icon-facebook"></i><span></span>
</a>
<a href="#" class="icon-button instagram">
  <i class="fa fa-instagram"></i><span></span>
</a>
```

I changed the Facebook `HTML` to the following and adjusted the `CSS` accordingly to get the icon working.

```html
<a href="#" class="icon-button facebook">
  <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i><span></span>
</a>
```

```css
html {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

body {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Wrapper */

.icon-button {
  background-color: white;
  /* border-radius: 2.6rem;*/
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  height: 2.6rem;
  line-height: 2.6rem;
  margin: 0 5px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  width: 2.6rem;
}


/* Circle */

.icon-button span {
  /* border-radius: 0;*/
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  width: 0;
}

.icon-button:hover span {
  border-radius: 25px;
  width: 2.6rem;
  height: 2.6rem;
  /*border-radius: 2.6rem;*/
  margin: -1.3rem;
  /*transform: rotate(20deg);*/
}


/* Icons */

.icon-button i {
  background: none;
  color: white;
  height: 2.6rem;
  left: 0;
  line-height: 2.6rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  width: 2.6rem;
  z-index: 10;
}

.facebook span {
  background-color: #3B5998;
}

.instagram span {
  background-color: #c32aa3;
  /*background-color: linear-gradient(#c32aa3, #c4302b);*/
}

.codepen span {
  background-color: #cb2027;
}

.icon-button .fa-facebook {
  color: #3B5998;
}

.icon-button .fa-instagram {
  color: #c32aa3;
}

.icon-button .fa-codepen {
  color: #cb2027;
}

.icon-button:hover .fa-facebook,
.icon-button:hover .fa-instagram,
.icon-button:hover .fa-codepen {
  color: white;
}

@media all and (max-width: 680px) {
  .icon-button {
    border-radius: 1.6rem;
    font-size: 0.8rem;
    height: 1.6rem;
    line-height: 1.6rem;
    width: 1.6rem;
  }
  .icon-button:hover span {
    width: 1.6rem;
    height: 1.6rem;
    border-radius: 1.6rem;
    margin: -0.8rem;
  }
  /* Icons */
  .icon-button i {
    height: 1.6rem;
    line-height: 1.6rem;
    width: 1.6rem;
  }
  body {
    padding: 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<a href="#" class="icon-button facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i><span></span></a>
<a href="#" class="icon-button instagram"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i><span></span></a>
<a href="#" class="icon-button codepen"><i class="fa fa-codepen"></i><span></span></a>
```

**Edit (linear gradient example)**

```css
html {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

body {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Wrapper */

.icon-button {
  background-color: white;
  /* border-radius: 2.6rem;*/
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  height: 2.6rem;
  line-height: 2.6rem;
  margin: 0 5px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  width: 2.6rem;
}


/* Circle */

.icon-button span {
  /* border-radius: 0;*/
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  width: 0;
}

.icon-button:hover span {
  border-radius: 25px;
  width: 2.6rem;
  height: 2.6rem;
  /*border-radius: 2.6rem;*/
  margin: -1.3rem;
  /*transform: rotate(20deg);*/
}


/* Icons */

.icon-button i {
  background: none;
  color: white;
  height: 2.6rem;
  left: 0;
  line-height: 2.6rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  width: 2.6rem;
  z-index: 10;
}

.instagram span {
  background: linear-gradient(#c32aa3, #333333);
}

.icon-button .fa-instagram {
  color: #c32aa3;
}

.icon-button:hover .fa-instagram {
  color: white;
}

@media all and (max-width: 680px) {
  .icon-button {
    border-radius: 1.6rem;
    font-size: 0.8rem;
    height: 1.6rem;
    line-height: 1.6rem;
    width: 1.6rem;
  }
  .icon-button:hover span {
    width: 1.6rem;
    height: 1.6rem;
    border-radius: 1.6rem;
    margin: -0.8rem;
  }
  /* Icons */
  .icon-button i {
    height: 1.6rem;
    line-height: 1.6rem;
    width: 1.6rem;
  }
  body {
    padding: 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<a href="#" class="icon-button instagram"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i><span></span></a>
```

Comment: Thanks. Also how can I edit use linear gradient in this snippet: 
.instagram span {
  background-color: #c32aa3;
  /*background-color: linear-gradient(#c32aa3, #c4302b);*/
}

Comment: @KillMe I updated my answer and added an example for you. For `linear-gradient`, use `background`, not `background-color`.

Comment: @KillMe Did this help you out?

Comment: Yeah. thanks that's works great!! Also is there any alternative to linear-gradientr?

Comment: @KillMe Not totally sure what you mean. It sounds like a new question is in order.

Comment: Okay no worries. Thanks for the help!!